# Can't load file from path

Tags: c#

I have an problem loading an xml from a path, because on my pc(and others) part of the path is mapped:
This is the path i have from the database:

> \serverName\files\System\Appldata\Application\3_5\TEST\Program\Version.xml

But on my computer the path looks like this:

> Y:\Application\3_5\TEST\Program

This is the code:

```
    var path = new DirectoryInfo(x.LocationName+@"\"+x.FolderName);
    var doc = new XmlDocument();

    //Loading the file
      doc.Load(path.FullName + @"\Version.xml");
```

Are there any way around this problem?

Comment: What is the value of `path.FullName` and what is `path`?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The path.FullName is \\serverName\files\System\Appldata\Application\3_5\TEST\Program\

Comment: Provide the code to calculate the path.

Comment: You should be able to use the full UNC path, assuming that the current account has rights to access it. However, note that your full path is missing a backslash at the start: `\\serverName\files\System\Appldata\Application\3_5\TEST\Program\Version.xml`

Comment: As long as you have the network path, local mappings should not pose a problem. There are ways to transform one into the other, but I don't see a problem here if you already have the UNC path. Please use "Path.Combine" instead of manually inserting slashes in paths though.

Comment: What is the value of x.LocationName and x.FolderName?

Comment: x.LocationName= \serverName\files\System\Appldata\Application\3_5\TEST\ and x.FolderName = Program

Comment: Just a sugestion use virtual path in your database and make a configurable _mapper_ that can map the virtual path to a real one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, do not try to concatenate by yourself the path and the filename.
Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)

```
 doc.Load(Path.Combine(path.FullName, "Version.xml"));
```

This requires the `using System.IO;`  at the beginning of your source file. 
Of course you could use both the mapped version or the full sharename only if you have the permissions to you remote folder. Also, if your database keeps the full sharename be sure that it is stored with the two initial backslash

**EDIT** Seeing your edit now, again, do not manually build your paths (and check if the info are valid)

```
var path = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(x.LocationName, x.FolderName));
if(!path.Exists)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid path retrieved:" + path.FullName);
    return;
}
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Path.Combine(path.FullName,"Version.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the file using network path. Please make sure that you are able to access the file from the file explorer on webserver.

Try this code:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var finalPath = Path.Combine(x.LocationName, x.FolderName, "Version.xml");
//Loading the file
doc.Load(finalPath);
```